# Julia use of JLD: WARNING: Module HDF5 uuid did not match cache file

Tags: save, julia

When I run using JLD I get the following warnings:

```
INFO: Recompiling stale cache file C:\Julia\PkgDir\lib\v0.4\JLD.ji for module JLD.
WARNING: Module HDF5 uuid did not match cache file
This is likely because module HDF5 does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does.
WARNING: deserialization checks failed while attempting to load cache from C:\Julia\PkgDir\lib\v0.4\JLD.ji
INFO: Precompiling module JLD...
INFO: Recompiling stale cache file C:\Julia\PkgDir\lib\v0.4\JLD.ji for module JLD.
WARNING: Module HDF5 uuid did not match cache file
This is likely because module HDF5 does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does.
__precompile__(true) but require failed to create a precompiled cache file
```

If I then run say:

```
A=ones(40)
save("c:\\OneDrive\\Model\\myfile.jld", "A", A)
```

I get the error:

```
UndefVarError: save not defined in include_string at loading.jl:288 in eval at
C:\Julia\PkgDir\v0.4\Atom\src\Atom.jl:3 [inlined code] from 
C:\Julia\PkgDir\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:39 in anonymous at 
C:\Julia\PkgDir\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:108 in withpath at 
C:\Julia\PkgDir\v0.4\Requires\src\require.jl:37 in withpath at 
C:\Julia\PkgDir\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:53 [inlined code] from 
C:\Julia\PkgDir\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:107 in anonymous at task.jl:58
```

I'm using Atom 1.8.0 and Julia 0.4.7. I'm using JLD as, to the best of my knowledge, it's the only pkg that allows me to write variables to file and preserve all of their attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue with JLD at one point and running `Pkg.update()` fixed it.  Updating to the latest stable Julia version before running the package update could also be helpful.